# Add drag event listener to iframe

Tags: javascript, drag-event

I create an `iframe` in JavaScript and add a drag enter event listener to it.
I wrote a small sample here:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kainanchen/pen/gOrRWRd)

```
drag.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false)
```

It works well in codepen.

My real project is in a chrome extension. I write the same code but the `dragenter` event works only from left/top boundaries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is from

```
border: none;
outline: none;
```

Also I tested

```
frameBorder = 0
border = 0
```

They will affect the dragenter as well.

I don't know if it only happens in chrome extension, and here is my solution

As I need to remove the border, I used

```
border-color: transparent;
```

Done!